# How to combine JSX component with dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-component

I'm displaying text that was stored in the database. The data is coming from firebase as a string (with newline breaks included). To make it display as HTML, I originally did the following:

```
<p className="term-definition"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: (definition.definition) ? definition.definition.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />') : ''}}></p>
```

This worked great. However there's one additional feature. Users can type `[word]` and that word will become linked. In order to accomplish this, I created the following function:

```
  parseDefinitionText(text){
    text = text.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
    text = text.replace(/\[([A-Za-z0-9'\-\s]+)\]/, function(match, word){
      // Convert it to a permalink
      return (<Link to={'/terms/' + this.permalink(word) + '/1'}>{word}</Link>);
    }.bind(this));
    return text;
  },
```

I left out the `this.permalink` method as it's not relevant. As you can see, I'm attempting to return a `<Link>` component that was imported from react-router.However since it's raw HTML, `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` no longer works properly.

So I'm kind of stuck at this point. What can I do to both format the inner text and also create a link?

Answer (score 2):

You could split the text into an array of Links + strings like so:

```
import {Link} from 'react-router';

const paragraphWithLinks = ({markdown}) => {
  const linkRegex = /\[([\w\s-']+)\]/g;

  const children = _.chain(
    markdown.split(linkRegex) // get the text between links
  ).zip(
    markdown.match(linkRegex).map( // get the links
      word => <Link to={`/terms/${permalink(word)}/1`}>{word}</Link> // and convert them
    )
  ).flatten().thru( // merge them
    v => v.slice(0, -1) // remove the last element (undefined b/c arrays are different sizes)
  ).value();

  return <p className='term-definition'>{children}</p>;
};
```

The best thing about this approach is removing the need to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. Using it is generally an **extremely bad idea** as you're potentially creating an XSS vulnerability. That may enable hackers to, for example, steal login credentials from your users.

In most cases you do not need to use `dangerouslySetHTML`. The obvious exception is for integration w/ a 3rd party library, which should still be considered carefully.

Comment: what's _.chain? Are you using underscorejs? I don't have that as part of this project and don't want to add additional dependencies.

Comment: It's from `lodash`. Very similar to underscore, and pretty great. I've given you the gist of how you might create your markdown parser - the implementation is up to you.

Comment: `_.chain` allows you to execute functions in sequence, feeding the input from one function to the next.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar situation, however the accepted solution wasn't a viable option for me.

I got this working with `react-dom` in a fairly crude way.  I set the component up to listen for click events and if the click had the class of `react-router-link`.  When this happened, if the item has a `data-url` property set it uses `browserHistory.push`.  I'm currently using an isomorphic app, and these click events don't make sense for the server generation, so I only set these events conditionally.

Here's the code I used:

```
import React from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

export default class PostBody extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if(! global.__SERVER__) {
      this.listener = this.handleClick.bind(this);
      window.addEventListener('click', this.listener);
    }
  }

  componentDidUnmount() {
    if(! global.__SERVER__) {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.listener);
    }
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    if(_.includes(e.target.classList, "react-router-link")) {
      window.removeEventListener("click", this.listener);
      browserHistory.push(e.target.getAttribute("data-url"));
    }
  }

  render() {
    function createMarkup(html) { return {__html: html}; };

    return (
      <div className="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 post-body">
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(this.props.postBody)} />
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

Hope this helps out!